# Rights needed to see database files in Properties dialog?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, security

I have a contractor setting up a database application. The database is set up, the login for the app is set as the database owner, but has only 'public' at the server level.

When the contractor logs into SSMS with the database login, he sees no information in the Database Properties > Files page -- the table is empty. However, `exec sp_helpdb database;` returns all the info that should be showing in Properties.

Are there any rights I can grant that will show the file info in Properties, without granting excessive rights to anything else?

(SQL Server 2008 R2)

Comment: I haven't tried it, but you could set up a custom report in SSMS that queries sys.databases and sys.database_files. I don't use SSMS for this kind of stuff so it doesn't bother me: but I know what you mean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly I believe you need to grant [VIEW DEFINITION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187113.aspx) to your contractor's account. You can do this only on the DBs you want the contractor to access.

Comment: Thanks, that put me on the right track -- I actually needed to grant VIEW ANY DEFINITION to get the files to show in the Properties dialog.