# SQL Server 2012: Users cannot see database properties

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssms

I migrated a database from SQL Server 2008 to 2012 and also the users.

Now the weird thing is that if the user connects to SSMS on the same server as the SQL Server engine, he can display database properties but he cannot when he uses SSMS to access it remotely (from another machine). He can log, run SQL queries but not display the properties.

Here is the error message:

[image]

Even stranger, if I log remotely with `sa`, I CAN display database properties but not as a normal user.

I looked around, tried many things, created new users in the new server. But same problem.

I tried this [Rights needed to see database files in Properties dialog?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15422/rights-needed-to-see-database-files-in-properties-dialog) in the Securables but the parameters do not seem to be saved. When I reopen they are gone - see screenshot

[image]

Please help

Comment: have you checked out database compatibility,  because you have migrated from sql server 2008 to 2012.  For sql server 2012 compatibility level 110.

Comment: I highly doubt that DB compatibility levels would have an effect on this.  Those control things like the Cardinality Estimator, not user permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem comes from the fact that all the remote SSMS were v 2008. When I logged in from another computer with SSMS 2012, I could display everything.

But we use the 2 versions: 2008 and 2012. Any one knows a quick fix to access a **SQL Server 2012** with a **SSMS 2008**?

Thank you

Comment: Just download SSMS 2014 and call it a day, it's totally free and can be downloaded by itself.  SSMS 2014 can still access the other major versions.  There are a few minor things you can't do with, say, a 2005 instance (double click an index to view it's properties and it will throw an error).

Comment: @KrisGruttemeyer I think that's the best thing to do! Thanks though!